# Text position fixed over image

Tags: html, css

I have this sample:

[link](https://jsfiddle.net/cbk2pkxv/)

```css
.header{
    background-image:url("http://orange.motorcitynewengland.com/img/bg/jeep-renegade.jpg");
    width:1920px;
    height:616px;
    background-size:contain;
}
span{
  font-size: 21px;
    color: white;
    position: absolute;
    left: 56%;
    transform: rotate(33deg);
    top: 86px;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
   <span>Low mileage</span>
</div>
```

I want to position the text on the blue.
The problem is that if you resize the browser, the text goes awry.

I want to keep the element position regardless of the browser size.
You please tell me how to do this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You must change the unit from **%** to **px** `left: 650px`

### CSS Code:

```
 .header{
        background-image:url("http://orange.motorcitynewengland.com/img/bg/jeep-renegade.jpg");
        width:1920px;
        height:616px;
        background-size:contain;
    }
    span{
      font-size: 21px;
        color: white;
        position: absolute;
        left: 650px;
        transform: rotate(33deg);
        top: 86px;
    }
```

[**Working Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/2xsj0c69/1/)

Comment: It is ok but the background image is not responsive, so the text is fixed.
You can make text and image responsive to stay in the same position?

Comment: if the text doesn't change you could add it directly to the image.

Answer (score 1):

```css
.header{
    background-image:url("http://orange.motorcitynewengland.com/img/bg/jeep-renegade.jpg");
    width:1920px;
    height:616px;
    background-size:contain;
 
}
span{
  font-size: 19px;
    color: white;
    position: absolute;
   left: 105%;
    transform: rotate(33deg);
    top: 10%;
 
  

}
```

```html
<div class="header">
   <span>Low mileage</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

if the **inner element** is absolute, **outer element** must be relative to position relative to **outter element**.

```css
.header{
    background-image:url("http://orange.motorcitynewengland.com/img/bg/jeep-renegade.jpg");
    width:1920px;
    height:616px;
    background-size:contain;
    position: relative;

}
span{
    font-size: 21px;
    color: white;
    position: absolute;
    left: 56%;
    transform: rotate(33deg);
    top: 86px;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
   <span>Low mileage</span>
</div>
```